# Show the series in the navigation regardless it's hidden or shown in highcharts.js?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

```
showInNavigator: true,
     navigatorOptions: {
        visible:true,
},
```

**I Added these lines in the series it is showing the series in the navigator when it's loaded but after selecting and deselecting it's not showing this series in the navigator. I want to show this series in the navigation no matter it's visible or not. It's working first time only but after enabling and disabling that series it get hidden**

Answer (score 1):

You can add an independent navigator series:

```
    series: [{
        ...,
        showInNavigator: false
    }, ...],

    navigator: {
        series: [{...}]
    },
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bj5xufqd/

**API Refernece:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator.series